# Problems uploading images to existing products Magmi Magento

Tags: image, magento-1.7, magmi

I am having an issue uploading images but clearing the image search path is not working to solve my issue.  (Found in another post)

This is the error i get:

> Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - error copying media/catalog/product/5/4/54402.jpg : download error,URL cmsdistribution.com/product-files/image/54402.jpg is unreachable
>   Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - error copying media/catalog/product/5/4/54402.jpg : download error,URL cmsdistribution.com/product-files/image/54402.jpg is unreachable
>   Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - error copying media/catalog/product/5/4/54402.jpg : download error,URL cmsdistribution.com/product-files/image/54402.jpg is unreachable

The media/catalog/product folder and everything below is set to 777 and the URL i am calling in the csv looks fine and i can find it in a simple browser (Seen 3 times above (once for image, small_image and thumbnail with the only other column in the sheet being sku))

Has anyone else played with image importing?  Am i missing something?

I have had to remove the http www dot etc from the codes above as i am being caught out for spamming in the post

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest svn version of Magmi. The image processor had a "bug" for handling redirected images (checking only 200 response on HEAD request for download check).
The latest svn version has a fix for this.

Comment: i am getting the error also in the 1.0.26 version.  Image attributes processor v1.0.26 - error copying media/catalog/product/t/e/team_alternate_kapuzen-jacke_wei_c3_9f_2c_s-516d7c95e4b0ee7450763780-14452.jpg : download error,URL http://www.alternate.de/p/230x230/8/Alternate_Team_Alternate_Kapuzen_Jacke@@81qjch00_3.png is unreachable

Comment: i tryed also version 1.0.26a, no luck !

Comment: The fix is not in plugin itself but in a common library file (fshelper.php) in magmi/inc directory. Try checkouting latest Git version (either on sourceforge or gitHub)